# Google Maps Static API does not show house number on map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I enable house numbers in the Google Maps Static API?

Screenshot from Google Maps.
[image]

Image from google maps static api.
[image: image from google maps s]

Let's vote this up: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174692137?pli=1

Comment: Google Maps is different from the APIs. Does the Google Maps Javascript API v3 have the house numbers on the tiles?

Comment: The native one (iOS, Android) does. I'll check if the web version does have the house numbers on it tomorrow!

Comment: Any luck @RichardLindhout, I have the same question

Comment: No luck, maybe someone at Google could answer like Richard Seroter. I'll try to contact him via Twitter

Comment: Heard back from him! "You're right that the Maps Static API doesn't support street numbers yet, but the product team is considering it for a future release."

Comment: The JS-api does not show house numbers for me either :(

Answer (score 1):

there is already an open feature request on the issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/174692137. I recommend starring the issue. Starring the issue provides Google Maps Platform Team with valuable feedback on the importance of the issue to their customers, and increases the issue's priority with the product engineering team.